# New to Homebrew, no pip install?

Tags: pip, ipython, homebrew, jupyter-notebook

I just downloaded homebrew, and want to download ipython notebook.

```
pip install ipython
-bash: pip: command not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: `brew install python` will install the latest Python2 along with its own pip.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a brew sudo install pip, and now I'll do sudo pip install for every package.